# gutenberg add classes to list items

Tags: theme-development, block-editor

how can I add a class to li elements when creating block templates? I get to here:

```
array( 'core/list', array( 
            'className' =>  'list-unstyled h5',
            'li'        =>  array(
                               'className'  =>  'list-inline-style'
                            )
) ),
```

which adds the classes to the `<ul>` but how do I add classes to the `<li>` element? Or something like that?